# Comparing two arrays of objects using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, foreach, nested-loops

I am having an issue with comparing two arrays. One is a fixed data set while the other is being generated dynamically.

A sample of the two arrays are as follows:

```
// Fixed list of 197 countries
$scope.countries = [
  {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"},
  {"name": "Albania", "code": "AF"},
  {"name": "Algeria", "code": "AF"},

  //...

  {"name": "Zimbabwe", "code": "ZW"}
];

//Dynamically generated list of matched countries

$scope.matches = [
  {"name": "Belgium"},
  {"name": "Ghana"}
];
```

At the end of the game a function will be run and a comparison of the two arrays will be made. As of right now I have tried (What seems like) almost every combination of this compare using angular.forEach and standard javascript loops. The issue comes when I try to log what countries haven't been matched.

This is the compare function I am running.

```
$scope.compareArrays = function(){
      angular.forEach($scope.countries, function(country,name){
        angular.forEach($scope.matches, function(match){
          if (country.name !== match.name) {
            console.log(country.name);
          } else {
            console.log("MATCHED");
          }
        });
      });
};
```

The function will find and log the countries that havent been matched...but it is logging the entire list of unmatched countries multiple times. Specifically once for every object in the "matches" array.

So for example if the matches array is the same as the sample above, it will log the unmatched countries list twice once with Belgium logging as "MATCHED" and the other time logging Belgium as an unmatched country (Same for Ghana but reversed obviously).

I simply want it to log a list of the unmatched countries once and that is all.

I'm hoping it is a simple oversight but cannot figure it out. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing here is (pseudo-code):

```
for each existing country
    for each country to be matched
        log country.name UNLESS it's a match
```

The thing is, even if all your existing countries **ARE** in the `matches` list, **each of your 197 existing countries** will ***NOT*** match any of the 196 other.

You actually need to be sure that each `country` (from the `countries` list) is not matched by **ANY** of the countries from `matches`: then and only then, it's actually an "*unmatched*" country.

---

Here's a nice way to get that list (using [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), which I highly recommend):

```
// Fixed list of 197 countries
var countries = [
  {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"},
  {"name": "Albania", "code": "AF"},
  {"name": "Algeria", "code": "AF"},
  {"name": "Zimbabwe", "code": "ZW"}
];

// Dynamically generated list of matched countries

var matches = [
  {"name": "Albania"},
  {"name": "Ghana"}
];

// Rejecting the countries that have "some" (at least one) match in the other list.
function compareArrays(countries, matches){
    return _.reject(countries, function(country) {
        return _.some(matches, function(match) {
            return country.name === match.name;
        });
    });
};

_.each(compareArrays(countries, matches), function(unmatched) {
    console.log(unmatched);
});

// Object {name: "Afghanistan", code: "AF"}
// Object {name: "Algeria", code: "AF"}
// Object {name: "Zimbabwe", code: "ZW"}
```

And here is a link to a [working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w1xLhhyv/1/).

---

Note that I haven't used any Angular stuff in that answer because it that problem is actually purely algorithmic related.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can skip counting the duplicated checks by somehow start the second loop where the first one currently is. I would have done this with an index and a for-loop:

```
$scope.compareArrays = function(){
  var c = $scope.countries;
  var m = $scope.matches;
  for(var i = 0;i < c.length;i++) {
    for(var j = i;j < m.length;j++) { // Notice the j = i;
      if (c[i].name !== m[j].name) {
        console.log(c[i].name);
      } else {
        console.log("MATCHED");
      }
    };
  });
};
```

I hope this answered your question, and hope you like plain JS too!

Answer (score 1):

You should break it up into smaller functions. For example, create a comparison function which will return `true` if `country` is not in your `matches` list:

```
function isUnmatched(country, matches) {
  return matches.every(function(matched){
    return country.name !== matched.name;
  });
}
```

Then create a function that will call `isUnmatched` for each country and return an array of unmatched countries:

```
function getUnmatched() {
  return countries.filter(function(country){
    return isUnmatched(country, matches);
  });
}
```

If your environment doesn't support `Array.prototype.every` and `Array.prototype.filter`, you can re-write the above as follows:

```
function isUnmatched(country, matches) {
  var i = matches.length;
  while (i--) {
    if (country.name === matches[i].name) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function getUnmatched() {
  var unmatched = [],
      i = countries.length,
      country;

  while (i--) {
    country = countries[i];
    if (isUnmatched(country, matches)) {
      // console.log(country.name)
      unmatched.push(country);
    }
  }

  return unmatched;
}
```

So if your lists look like this:

```
var countries = [
  {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"},
  {"name": "Albania", "code": "AF"},
  {"name": "Algeria", "code": "AF"}
];

var matches = [
  {"name": "Albania"},
  {"name": "Algeria"}
];
```

Then:

```
var unmatched = getUnmatched(); 
//=> [{"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"}]
```

[JSFiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/yo28gcrv/2/)
[JSFiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/bnL0pdf4/)

Answer (score 0):

1. put all the names from `matches` list into a hash as a key:

   var index = {};
    matches. forEach(name => index [name] = true;)
2. iterate through `countries` and check if current one exist in `index`:

   for (let country of countries)
        if (!index.hasOwnProperty(country. name))
            console.log(country.name, ' is not included');
3. get O(N+M) instead of O(N*M)